# Machine Learning Implementation

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am new to ML and I wanted to implement a Linear Regression to predict a golfer's scores based on certain feature supplied to my model. I would like a review to see if I'm implementing this correctly and any tips to make my model more efficient. Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LassoCV
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

df = pd.read_csv("/Users/aus10/Desktop/PGA/History/Workday_Charity/PGA_TEST_FEAT.csv")
df_model = df.copy()
scaler = StandardScaler()

features = [['SG:ATG', 'FH', 'SG:APP', 'AVG:Putts:GIR', 'SG:Putting']]
for feature in features:
    df_model[feature] = scaler.fit_transform(df_model[feature])

SG_data = pd.read_csv("/Users/aus10/Desktop/PGA/History/Workday_Charity/SG.csv")
x = df.iloc[:,1:6]  #independent columns
y = df.iloc[:,-1]    #target column i.e price range

results = []

# fit final model
model = LassoCV(cv=5, random_state=0)
model.fit(x, y)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=2)

model.fit(x_train, y_train)

y_pred = model.predict(x_test)

print( round(r2_score(y_test, y_pred),2) )

# define one new data instance

index = 0
count = 0

while count < len(SG_data):
    name = SG_data.loc[index].at['Name']
    strokes_gained_atg = SG_data.loc[index].at['SG:ATG']
    fairways_hit = SG_data.loc[index].at['FH']
    strokes_gained_approach = SG_data.loc[index].at['SG:APP']
    average_putts_gir = SG_data.loc[index].at['AVG:Putts:GIR']
    strokes_gained_putting = SG_data.loc[index].at['SG:Putting']
    

    Xnew = [[ strokes_gained_atg, fairways_hit, strokes_gained_approach, average_putts_gir, strokes_gained_putting ]]
    # make a prediction
    ynew = model.predict(Xnew)
    # show the inputs and predicted outputs
    results.append(
        {
            'Name': name,
            'Projection': (round(ynew[0],2))
        }
        )
    index += 1
    count += 1
sorted_results = sorted(results, key=lambda k: k['Projection'], reverse=True)

df = pd.DataFrame(sorted_results, columns=[
    'Name', 'Projection'])
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('/Users/aus10/Desktop/PGA/Regressions/Linear_Regressions/Results/Workday_Projections_LR_Lasso.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'center'})
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 100)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
writer.save()
```

attached are the two csv files.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BH7_3Z0o2_VAI81p0ZuVZ3-0kO0n7ZrU5iBHF-WTAaw/edit?usp=sharing

[image: PGA_TEST_FEAT]
[image: SG_data]

Comment: So PGA_TEST_FEAT contains all the statistic related to fantasy performance. I used a feature selection method to find the features that correlated most with fantasy output. The SG_data is all the current stats for each golf prior to the tournament. @Reinderien

Comment: @Reinderien done